# Automate on Scroll (aos) doesn't load in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jquery-animate

I am struggling with any task requiring the smallest bit of brain function. The task I'm currently struggling with is adding the [AOS library](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/) to my site on Wordpress.

I added the following code to my full-width-page.php template in the Wordpress Editor:

```
<script> AOS.init(); </script>
```

In addition, I added the following code under Appearance > Theme Settings > Style > External JS field & External CSS field

```
<script src="uploads/aos-master/dist/aos.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uploads/aos-master/dist/aos.css">
```

After all of that, I put the data-aos attribute to html element that I want to animate, like so:

```
<div data-aos="fade-up";>
<h2>TEST TEST TEST</h2>
</div>
```

But then... nothing happens ;(

Please, if it's possible to set up, share with me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure aos stylesheet and javascript file loaded correctly? You can use Chrome's or Firefox's debugger on page (Chrome's Shortcut is Ctrl(or CMD)+Shift+i)

also you can change stylesheet and javascript file codes with code below;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.2.0/aos.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, man! I tried the page debugger and unfortunately, it didn't work. I'm still amped that you told me about it cause I didn't know. In addition, I changed the links as you told me, which actually made the header disappear, so I feel like I'm one step closer. I also cleared both my browser cache and the cache from the WordPress end, after changing the links.

Comment: Maybe I should also say that I'm using a child theme, so I copied my full-width template into my child theme and initialized AOS at the top there. I don't know if that may be creating some type of problem

Comment: Ok, I am an idiot. I actually read into debugging and saw that I had the totally wrong impression. I inspected the js in the console and actually saw an error with the Initializing code in my full-width-page template. I cut the code from there and pasted it into my external java script field and it worked!

Comment: I happening to me the same, for some reason that I don't have an idea the problem is with this line in functions wp_enqueue_script( 'aos_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/aos-2.3.0/aos-2.3.0.js', array(), true ); after the array it is optional put the version, but if I put it,  the enqueue script not work. don't know why...